# Command or tool to interpret and read asciidoctor syntax through terminal?

Tags: terminal, software-installation, utilities, free-software, asciidoc

For a `.adoc` file to write documentation, it based on the `asciidoctor` syntax, is possible through GUI use either `VSCode` or `AsciiDocFX` to see a *preview*. Therefore the `asciidoctor` syntax is rendered/interpreted to be read it.

For the `terminal` what software - if exists - would do the same job about to render/interpret the `asciidoctor` syntax to read it? I mean something like the execution of:

- `<toolname> tutorial.adoc`

Consider as example: have a `html` file and use `w3m` to interpret and read it.
Therefore I want practically the same behavior like `man <commandname>`, read a documentation with a pretty format.

Comment: Does pandoc support it?

Answer (score 0):

Asciidoctor itself can convert .adoc files to various formats, including HTML. While it doesn't natively support terminal viewing, you can convert the AsciiDoc file to HTML and then use a text-based browser like w3m, lynx, or elinks to view it in the terminal. The process would be something like this:

```
asciidoctor -b html5 tutorial.adoc -o tutorial.html
```

w3m tutorial.html